# How to detect Celery Connection failure and switch to failover then back?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

So our use case might be out of the remit of what Celery can do, but I thought I'd ask...

**Use Case**

We are planning on using a hosted/managed RabbitMQ cluster backing which Celery will be using for it's broker.
We want to ensure that our app has 0 downtime (obviously) so we're trying to figure out how we can handle the event when our upstream cluster has a catastrophic failure whereby the entire cluster is unavailable.

Our thought is that we have a standby Rabbit cluster that when the connection drops, we can automatically switch Celery to use that connection instead.

In the meantime, Celery is determining whether the master cluster is up and running and when it is, all of the publishers reconnect to the master, the workers drain the backup cluster and when empty, switch back onto the master.

**The issue**

What I'm having difficulty with is capturing the connection failure as it seems to happen deep within celery as the Exception doesn't bubble up to the app.

I can see that Celery has a `BROKER_FAILOVER_STRATEGY` configuration property, which would handle the initial swap, but it (seemingly) is only utilised when failover occurs, which doesn't fit our use case of swapping back to the master when it is back up.

I've also come across Celery's "bootsteps", but these are applied after Celery's own "Connection" bootstep which is where the exception is being thrown.

I have a feeling this approach is probably not the best one given the limitations I've been finding, but has anyone got any ideas on how I'd go about overriding the default Connection bootstep or achieving this via a different means?

Comment: did you manage any solution related with this?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite old, but maybe useful to someone. I'm usin FastApi with Celery 5.2.

run_api.py file:

```
import uvicorn

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port=8893
    print("Starting API server on port {}".format(port))
    uvicorn.run("endpoints:app", host="localhost", port=port, access_log=False)
```

endpoints.py file:

```
import threading
import time
import os
from celery import Celery
from fastapi import FastAPI
import itertools   
import random 

# Create object for fastAPI
app = FastAPI()

# Create and onfigure Celery to manage queus
# ----
celery = Celery(__name__)

celery.conf.broker_url = ["redis://localhost:6379"] 
celery.conf.result_backend = "redis://localhost:6379"
celery.conf.task_track_started = True
celery.conf.task_serializer = "pickle"
celery.conf.result_serializer = "pickle"
celery.conf.accept_content = ["pickle"]

def random_failover_strategy(servers):
    # The next line is necessary to work, even you don't use them:
    it = list(servers)  # don't modify callers list
    shuffle = random.shuffle
    for _ in itertools.repeat(None):
        # Do whatever action required here to obtain the new url
        # As an example, ra.
        ra = random.randint(0, 100)
        it = [f"redis://localhost:{str(ra)}"]
        celery.conf.result_backend = it[0]
        shuffle(it)
        yield it[0]

celery.conf.broker_failover_strategy = random_failover_strategy

# Start the celery worker. I start it in a separate thread, so fastapi can run in parallel
worker = celery.Worker()

def start_worker():
    worker.start()

ce = threading.Thread(target=start_worker)
ce.start()
# ----

@app.get("/", tags=["root"])
def root():
    return {"message": ""}


@app.post("/test")
def test(num: int):
    task = test_celery.delay(num)
    print(f'task id: {task.id}')
    return {
        "task_id": task.id,
        "task_status": "PENDING"}

@celery.task(name="test_celery", bind=True)
def test_celery(self, num):
    self.update_state(state='PROGRESS')
    print("ENTERED PROCESS", num)
    time.sleep(100)
    print("EXITING PROCESS", num)
    return {'number': num}

@app.get("/result")
def result(id: str):
    task_result = celery.AsyncResult(id)
    if task_result.status == "SUCCESS":
        return {
            "task_status": task_result.status,
            "task_num": task_result.result['number']
            }
    else:
        return {
            "task_status": task_result.status,
            "task_num": None
            }
```

Place both files in the same folder. Run python3 run_api.py.

Enjoy!